# How to use grep?

Tags: linux, regex, grep

I need to find file from `ls - l` by using grep and certain regexp.

In particular I need greep to see certain file ending, like let's say `.txt` but only using regex.

So it should be something like

```
ls -l | grep '^.+\.txt$'
```

But that doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using `ls -l *.txt`?  Also note that with the eoln match ($), this will not pick up symlinks.  With extended regexp (as Matt mentions), you might want to use '^.+\.txt\>'
    $ ls -l *.txt
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 arcege arcege 8 2011-04-07 09:04 file.txt -> realfile
    $ ls -l | grep -E '^.+\.txt$'
    $ ls -l | grep -E '^.+\.txt\>'
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 arcege arcege 8 2011-04-07 09:04 file.txt -> realfile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the -E flag for grep:

```
-E, --extended-regexp
    Interpret  PATTERN  as  an extended regular expression (ERE, see
    below).  (-E is specified by POSIX.)
```

Comment: Hm.. Damn inattentiveness, I tried it but didn't specify the correct path :D